# Omniauth OpenId authentication returns nil on user_info

Tags: openid, devise, omniauth, google-openid

I am using Ruby 1.9.2 + Rails 3 + Devise + Omniauth and trying to authenticate users with Openid.

My providers on omniauth.rb are

```
provider :open_id, OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp')

provider :open_id, OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp'),
 {:name => "google", :identifier => "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" }

provider :open_id, OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp'),
 {:name => "yahoo", :identifier => "https://me.yahoo.com" }
```

I am redirected correctly to the providers and callback is called. However for myopenid, it always returns nil on the `user_info` hash. And for both google or yahoo it returns a 400 (Bad Request) when the callback url is called.

For google and yahoo, I added `:required => []` param (not really sure what id does) and it didnt return the 400 error, but again `user_info` was nil

Answer (score 0):

It could be permissions.  Try Changing ('tmp') to ('./tmp')